# Prove or give a counter-example of this statemant for analytic differential equations in $(\mathbb{C}^n, 0)$:

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading the book called Lectures on Analytic Differential Equations. Graduate Studies in Mathematics 86 by Yulij Ilyashenko and Sergei Yakovenko and I encountered this statement written in ink by someone else: 
Every analytic differential equation whose linear part has its collection of proper values in the Siegel domain has in its formal normal form a countable number of resonant monomials.
I would like to know if this statement is false or true.
Personally, I believe that it is not true, but I have been unable to find a counter-example, also I tried to prove it, but I am lost to where or how to begin the proof.
Thank you very much.